# Error "MySQL server has gone away"

Tags: php, mysql

Este error me aparece cuando trato hacer un `prepared statement`. El código para un `CRUD` lo tenia sin `prepared statement` y me funcionaba sin ningún error, pero ahora que lo pase a `prepared statement` me sale eso.

¿Cuál puede ser el error? He leído que hay que cambiar algunas configuraciones de `MySQL` pero me parece raro que este error solo me aparezca con `prepared statement`, si no le pongo el `printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));` me dice que guarda pero la verdad es que no lo hace y no aparece en la db.

Mi código

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO establecimiento_educacional (rbd, idagno, idestablecimiento_estado, idregion, idprovincia, idcomuna, iddependencia, idarea_geografica, nombre, direccion, fono, mail_ee, celular, nombre_director, mail_director, res_rec_of, fecha) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

 $stmt=mysqli_prepare(conecta(),$sql);

 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "iiiiiiiisssssssis", $rbd, $agno, $establecimiento_estado, $region, $provincia, $comuna, $dependencia, $area_geografica, $nombre, $direccion, $fono, $mail_ee, $celular, $nombre_director, $mail_director, $res_rec_of, $fecha);


  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

El código de conecta()

```
$db['db_host'] = "localhost";
$db['db_user'] = "root";
$db['db_pass'] = "";
$db['db_name'] = "col";


foreach($db as $key => $value){
    define(strtoupper($key),$value);

    }


function conecta()
{
    $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);  

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Fallo la conexión: " . mysqli_connect_error();

}

return $con;
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrarnos el código que hay en `conecta()`? Puedes pulsar en [edit] para agregarlo a la pregunta. Gracias.

Comment: Ya lo agrege pero no se si es eso ya que me funciona para el crud sin prepared statement, para llenar selects y otras cosas. Para llenar los selects uso require_once(son funciones) y para conectar a la base de datos uso include

Comment: Creo que necesitas refinar algo más tu código. Por lo pronto, en vez de esto: `$stmt=mysqli_prepare(conecta(),$sql);` intenta algo así: `$con=conecta(); if ($con) {$stmt=mysqli_prepare($con,$sql); //resto del código } else { echo "No hay conexión"; }` Puede que el hecho de estar pasando directamente un método como parámetro de la conexión te esté trayendo problemas. `mysqli` es quisquilloso con ciertas funciones y parámetros.

Comment: Me funciono! Muchas gracias! La verdad es que prefería ocupar una funcion para conectar por que es mas ordenado pero veo que mysqli tiene problemas con eso.

Comment: Lo de la función no está mal, de hecho, la usas aquí: `$con=conecta();`. No es que tengas que renunciar a ella, sino dejar de pasarla directamente como parámetro, lo cual podría ser considerado una mala práctica, de hecho, es chocante pasar como parámetro una función dentro de otra función.  Y, te recomendaría que uses el estilo orientado a objetos, porque es más claro.

Answer (score 1):

Estás pasando como parámetro una función dentro de otra función:

```
$stmt=mysqli_prepare(conecta(),$sql);
            ^
        Una función     
                        ^
                   Otra función
```

Esto escapa a los estándares de programación y, nada te asegura que `mysqli_prepare` reconozca tu objeto conexión como válido en ese caso.

Guarda lo que devuevle `conecta()` en una variable y le pasas esa variable a `mysqli_prepare`.

De paso, puedes controlar si hay conexión o no.

```
$con=conecta(); 
if ($con) 
{
    $stmt=mysqli_prepare($con,$sql); 
    //resto del código 
} else { 
    echo "No hay conexión"; 
}
```

Comment: @Marcos sí tiene retorno: `return $con;`